# How to make D-LINK switch IP permanent

Tags: ip, switch, reset, d-link

I have procured a new D-Link Switch. I have changed its default ip address from **10.90.90.90** to a new ip address. eg - **192.168.100.101**. But I am unable set the ip permanently. Whenever I power off the switch its ip is getting reset to **10.90.90.90**. How do I make this ip change Permanent?

Comment: Save the configuration?

Comment: how to save the configuration?

Comment: I have no idea. What does the documentation say?